# My pair <double, double> format function will not operate when called

Tags: c++

I am writing a code with a `pair <double, double>` format function, but the function will not operate when called.

I am still learning C++, so maybe this format just isn't the way to go. Here is the prompt question in case it helps or anybody needs it to see where I was trying to go with my code.

> Write a function that calculates the total amount due on a receipt. Your function should be able to take in any number of decimal values and a sales tax rate. The function should return the subtotal (total of all items without tax) and the receipt total (total of all items with tax).
>
> (Ex.) Given a sales tax rate of 8.25% (0.0825) and the following item prices: 1.35, 2.38, 3.56, 7.89, 10.25, 3.31, 5.67
>
> Your function should calculate that the total without tax is 34.41 and the total with tax is 37.2488

And here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

pair <double, double> total(int itemCount, vector<double> itemPrices)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
        sum += i;
    }
  
    return {sum, sum + sum * 0.0825};
}

int main(int argc, char const * argv[])
{
    int itemCount = 0;
    cout << "Enter the number of items: ";
    cin >> itemCount;
    vector <double> itemPrices(itemCount);
    cout << "Enter item prices: " << endl;
  
    for(int i = 0; i < itemCount; ++i)
    {
        cin >> itemPrices[i];
    }
  
    pair <double, double> val = total(itemCount, itemPrices);
    double totalWithoutTax = val.first;
    double totalWithTax = val.second;
    return 0;
}
```

I was told by a friend that this format would help, but I am struggling a bit with it.

Edit: Hmm, I think I might just need to scrap this code since I think it's a bit beyond what I understand of C++ right now. To clarify to anyone trying to get the issue is, the output I get when the code runs is:

```
Enter the number of items: 7
Enter item prices: 
1.35
2.38
3.56
7.89
10.25
3.31
5.67
```

From what I understand about functions is that, once defined, they are supposed to operate when called. But when I call the `total()` function, it does nothing and the program ends. So, I am really just confused.

Comment: Feedback: the shown code is completely broken. `total()` does not total anything, but simply adds up all numbers from `0` to `itemCount-1`, and completely ignores the `itemPrices`. Which are passed by value, which means a completely useless, redundant, and expensive vector copy construction. If the intent of `total()` is to add up all `itemPrices`, then: 1) it doesn't do that, 2) `itemCount` is not needed, use `std::vector::size`, and passing in `itemPrices` (by reference) is sufficient. What does "struggling a little bit" mean?

Comment: `sum += i` should be `sum += itemPrices.at(i)`.

Comment: You're never doing anything with the pair after you get it. That's why it "does nothing"

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik will do. I figure #include<vector> &
#include<iostream> would work just as well to get everything to work. I just tried it, they do.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `total` function.

Change `sum += i` to `sum += itemPrices.at(i)`, then add `std::cout` at the end of the program before returning zero.

```
cout << totalWithTax << '\n' << totalWithoutTax << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I still think I am going to stay away from this style of coding until I better comprehend C++ but I am glad to know what would fix that tricky bit of code!